# How to get pagination within my searchpage - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, pagination

I have a search bar on the mainpage of my website. when i search for companies and click 'search' it redirects to a page http://mydomain.com/searchresults. (NOTE: i removed the controller name 'home' with url routing)

i don't have any searchterms or results in my url. it's just a clean url.

when i try to implement pagination into that page it's not working because when i go to the next page, the searchterm is gone and it shows all the companies from my database.

How can i add pagination to this page?

My controller:

```
    function searchresults()
    {   
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);

        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
    }
```

My model:

```
function get_search($match, $match2)
{
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
        AND (Postcode LIKE '%".$this->input->post('cookie')."%')

        GROUP BY `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);

        return $result->result();
}
```

My search page:

```
<form name="input" action="searchresults" method="post">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="70">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" required="true" size="14" placeholder="Postcode..." name="cookie" value="<?= $this->input->cookie('postcode', TRUE); ?>" >

<input type="submit" value="Zoeken">

</form>
```

My searchresults page:

```
<div id="bigcontent">
<h1>Companies found: <?= count($query); ?></h1>
<?= br(1); ?>
<h2>Company:</h2>
<?= br(1); ?>
<?= $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
<?= br(2); ?>
<hr/>
<?php foreach($query as $item):?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bedrijven/<?= $item->idbedrijven?>"><h3><?= $item->Bedrijfsnaam   ?></h3></a>
    <p><b>Categorie:</b> <?= $item->Categorie ?></p>
    <p><small><?php echo $item->Profiel ?></p>
    <p><b><?php echo $item->Email ?></b></p>
    <p><b>Postcode:</b> <?php echo $item->Postcode ?></p>
    <p><b>Tags:</b></p>
    </small>
    <hr/>
<?php endforeach;?>
<br />
<<<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">Terug</a>
```

i tried something like:

(i loaded the pagination library in my autoload.php file)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/searchresults';
$config['total_rows'] = $data['query'];
$config['per_page'] = 4;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

but it did not work.

I hope it's clear what i want.

Comment: In your model try replacing `$this->input->post('search')` with `$match`. You have assigned `$this->input->post('search')` to `$match` in your controller.

Comment: 'search' is the name of my searchbox. without that i can't search.

Comment: YES. And you have assigned it's value to `$match` variable in your controller. `$match = $this->input->post('search');` Then you are calling the model `$this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);`. In `function get_search($match, $match2)` present in your model, the $match value will contain your `search input value`. You can also use `$this->input->post('search');` in you model but the whole concept of MVC will be of no point.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, codeigniter has a pagination class, which is pretty much useful for any kind of pagination.

I can see that you have added the config parameters, but not initialized the pagination. You have not even loaded the pagination library. Please follow [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) to get the library loaded and initialize.

I have used it in my live site [EduSanjal](http://edusanjal.com) and it works well. You can search and see there by yourself.

I hope that answers your question.

Regards.

Comment: I did load the library in autoload.php. will add that to my question. i also added the $this->pagination->initialize but i just added the options i've tried. this does not answer my question at all.

Answer (score 0):

As @openrijal mentioned it doesn't seem like you have initialized pagination library correctly.
I would first try and follow a simple example such as [this one](http://phpmaster.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/)...just to be sure you can paginate through your records.

I think one of the main things is that you are not sending the limit and current page to your model to limit the results that you get back, you are just passing match1/match2. Check the tutorial and look at the guy's "fetch_countries" function in his model.

Once you have simple pagination through all results then attach the search term to your pagination links so you can also pass this to the model (add another parameter) to limit the search results further

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why i dislike codeigniter. It promises to give everything yet fails when little bit complicacy arises.

None the less, here is a dirty way to handle.

1st you need to build the query string from the `GET` variable. but before that, you need to unset the `$_GET['page']` variable. (CI adds it autmatically).

Hence the code becomes.....

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))unset($_GET['page']);
```

Now build the query with rest of the search criterias.

```
$q = http_build_query($_GET);
```

Now change the base url to following:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/searchresults?'.$q
```

That's it.

---

## update

```
function searchresults()
    {   
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);


        /*--- here comes the part --*/

       if(isset($_GET['page']))unset($_GET['page']);
       $q = http_build_query($_GET);

      // Rest pagination code as shown in CI docs.

        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags();
    }
```

Here you can autoload only the library. Not the configs. You need to set it insdie the method.

Comment: 'This is one of the reasons why i dislike codeigniter. It promises to give everything yet fails when little bit complicacy arises.' oh yes sometimes i'm sick of that. anyway. thanks i will try this :)

Comment: can't get it to work. i know how pagination works for normal records. but it just does not work with my searchpage bacause it removes my searchterm when i click on page 2 for example.

Comment: post the method which is handling the search. You need to add the above code there.

Comment: i posted the method in my question. or am i missing something.

Comment: updated. The point to be noted is, you need to pass the query string each time the method is revoked. So pagination code must go inside the method.

Comment: the main problem is when i visit http://mydomain.com/searchresults it gives me the results. but when i visut http://mydomain.com/searchresults/2 (2 for the second page for pagination) my searchterm is gone and it shows all my factories.

Comment: set `$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;`

Comment: that does not work. still the same problem. you can look at it yourself go to http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl fill in the postcode 9101 in the dialog and click the green button. now just click on the blue search button on the main page. it will show you 8 companies. when you click on the second page (pagination) it show's you 13.

Comment: i am not seeing any 2nd page link in the search result page. where it is?

Comment: sorry got them commented out. here they are. http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/searchresults

Comment: there are some issues here.... your 1st request is POST with a cookie value 9101. Then the link becomes GET. So the post param is lost. Hence, abve code fails due to inconsistency. Now, you need to chose either GET or POST but don't chose both as it will make some pages bookmarkable and some can't. That's a bad idea. GET paginations are easy. POST is a little complicated with the invlovement of `sessions`. Unless you explicitely need POST request, change the form to GET.

Comment: allright. i changed my form to get but now my search isn't working anymore.

Comment: and yes. my pagination does not work. but first things first.

Comment: oh yes. that's true. let's try.

Comment: there could be 100s of things which can go wrong. post the updated code.

Comment: if(strlen($_GET['cookie']) > 0){ $match2 = $_GET['cookie']; } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }

Comment: NOTE: i have this in my index.php $config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem yesterday. It was a hell of a task to get this working.
Two people helped me in chat so we could try some things without a lot of comments.

See the solution here: [$offset not working for pagination codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789863/offset-not-working-for-pagination-codeigniter)

Also the question before that one:

[Records not limited on searchpage using codeigniter pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775206/records-not-limited-on-searchpage-using-codeigniter-pagination)