# Records not limited on searchpage using codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination, limit

**Situation**

I have a searchform which redirects to a searchresults page in which I want to implement Codeigniter Pagination.
My limit is not working. So all the results are shown instead of my `$limit = 4;`

Here is my controller code:

```
    function searchresults()
    {   

        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
        $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2);

        $limit = 4;
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'home/searchresults/';
        $config['total_rows'] = count($data['query']);
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }
```

**Question**

What could be the problem? Am I missing something?

---

### EDIT

I still can't get it to work. this is what i have so far.

Controller:

```
    function searchresults()
    {   

        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'home/searchresults/';
        $config['per_page'] = 4;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        //$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0); /*large number as limit to retrieve all the rows*/           
        $data['query_curr'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_search($match, $match2, $limit, $offset)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            //rest of the code
    }
```

My views:

```
    <?php foreach($query_curr as $item):?>
    <br/>
    <div class="logo1">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bedrijven/<?= $item['idbedrijven'] ?>"><img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/t/Aluminum-Body-Violin-or-Cello-Makers-Compass-Draw-Shave-Plane-Good-Shape-/00/s/NDYwWDU1MQ==/$(KGrHqJ,!hYF!sl)RwymBQiLq5Cn4Q~~60_35.JPG"></a>
    </div>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>bedrijven/<?= $item['idbedrijven'] ?>"><h3><?= $item['Bedrijfsnaam']   ?></h3></a>
        <p>
        <b>Categorie:</b>
        <?php echo "" . $item['Categorie'] . ", &nbsp;" ; ?>
        </p>
        <small>
            <p><b><?php echo $item['Email'] ?></b></p>
            <p><b>Postcode:</b> <?php echo $item['Postcode'] ?></p>
            <p><b>Plaats:</b> <?php echo $item['Plaats'] ?></p>
            <p><b>Tags:</b></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['Profiel'] ?></p>   
        </small>
        <br/><hr/>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <br/>
    <?= $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    <br />
    <br />
```

Comment: does it work now? If not try this http://pastebin.com/yNhQLBnm . As I have told you before, with your post input data, pagination won't work as it gets expire when you are using pagination links. You have to keep it in a session. Anyway, try this and let me know your stat. Thanks.

Comment: It works now. and i will try your code tommorrow. going home now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set offset and limit when you query from the database to make pagination work.

your get_search model should be like this

```
function get_search($match, $match2, $limit, $offset){
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    /*Rest of the code*/
}
```

your current query becomes

```
$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0); /*large number as limit to retrieve all the rows*/
```

You need to query another time with offset and limit like this

```
$data['query_curr'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
```

Here, $config['per_page'] is the limit and the offset is taken from the url segment( You have to initialize url helper. You need to use this `query_curr` variable in the view. This is the way to use pagination and correct number of rows will be shown.

Last thing, you don't have to send create_links() as variable in the view. You can use that directly in the view.

**UPDATE:**

Change your `searchresult` function to this

```
function searchresults()
{   

    $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
    $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
    $match = $this->input->post('search');
    if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }
    $data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0);
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'home/searchresults/';
    $config['total_rows'] = count($data['query']);
    $config['per_page'] = 4;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    //$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0); /*large number as limit to retrieve all the rows*/           
    $data['query_curr'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
    $this->load->view('views/header');
    $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
    $this->load->view('views/footer');
}
```

Comment: I get a problem. the limit is still not working and no links are shown. I've loaded the pagination and url helper in autoload.php I post my current code in the op

Comment: NOTE: The Links are working. when i set the limit to 1 for example there are more links then when I set it to 10. but there are still 12 records shown (as what I searched for)

Comment: You have removed `$config['total_rows']` from `searchresults`. But you need to have that to pagination to work. I am updating my answer. Check that.

Comment: ok i changed that. but still. 12 results and 3 links < 1 2 3 >

Comment: That's what you should get. 12 results, 4 per page. You  probably have 12 entries in database that are matched. So you are getting 12 entries. If you want to have 10 results, change limit to 10 instead of 2147483647 in your `data['query']`. I used that to retrieve all the matched result.

Comment: I changed my code now. I've set a limit and an offset using segment(3) and now i get this: http://i.imgur.com/TMG5xSd.png

Comment: Which line did you changed? I meant you to change `$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0);` to `$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 10, 0);` if you want 10 result.

Comment: sorry I am talking in two questions. Just look at my other question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789863/offset-not-working-for-pagination-codeigniter But i set my limit and offset in my sql query but i get an error. That error is not related to this so look at my other question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30755/discussion-between-sakibmoon-and-kees-sonnema)