# $offset not working for pagination codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination, offset

I am trying to implement Pagination into my searchresults page. I've asked this question yesterday with no succes [Records not limited on searchpage using codeigniter pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775206/records-not-limited-on-searchpage-using-codeigniter-pagination)

and the problem I have now is a bit different.

**Situation**

My pagination links are working and i see the url change like this: http://example.com/home/searchresults/2 (for the second page of pagination) etc.
But all the searchresults are shown. When I edit the limit to 1 I get more links, so that's working properly.

**Question**

What could be this stupid problem? I think it has to do with my Total_rows

My controller:

```
    function searchresults()
    {   
        $this->breadcrumbs->page = array('link'=> base_url().'home/search' ,'title' => 'Bedrijven Zoeken' );            
        $this->breadcrumbs->method = array('link'=> base_url().'home/searchresults' ,'title' => 'Zoekresultaten' );
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = $this->breadcrumbs->get();
        $match = $this->input->post('search');
        if(strlen($this->input->post('cookie')) > 0){ $match2 = $this->input->post('cookie'); } else{ $match2 = '9101'; }

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $limit = 4;
        $offset=($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'home/searchresults/';
        $config['total_rows'] = count($this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, $limit, $offset ));
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;   

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        //$data['query'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, 2147483647, 0); /*large number as limit to retrieve all the rows*/           
        $data['query_curr'] = $this->bedrijven_model->get_search($match, $match2, $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3) );
        $this->load->view('views/header');
        $this->load->view('views/searchresults', $data);
        $this->load->view('views/footer');
    }
```

My model:

```
function get_search($match, $match2, $limit, $offset=0)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
    session_start();
    };
    /*
    $string = implode($_SESSION['postcodes'], '|');
    $string2 = $_SESSION['searched_post_code'];
    */
    $postcodes = (is_array($_SESSION['postcodes']) ? $_SESSION['postcodes'] : array());
    $postcodes[] =  $_SESSION['searched_post_code'];
    $postcodes = array_filter(filter_var_array($postcodes, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
    $string = join(',', $postcodes);

        if (!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])) { 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
            JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
            JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
            WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
            OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
            AND (Postcode IN ($string))

            GROUP BY `Categorie`,  `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`";
            $query = $this->db->query($query);
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
            echo '<pre>';
            echo '</pre>';
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
      }
```

I hope someone can help me with this. I am struggling with this for almost 3 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your limit/offset inside the `$query`string:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
        AND (Postcode IN ($string)) 
        GROUP BY `Categorie`,  `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` 
        LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$limit;

       $result = $this->db->query($query);
       return $result->result_array();
```

Comment: What happens if you change the LIMIT line to this: `LIMIT ".$limit.", 0";` ?

Comment: i changed it to LIMIT '$limit', '$offset' "; but i still get an sql error. but the output looks like this now. http://i.imgur.com/Oy7xB6P.png

Comment: That's not what I asked. See what `LIMIT ".$limit.", 0";`gets you.

Comment: that makes no difference.. $offset outputs 0 so changing 0 by 0 doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wrong. http://i.imgur.com/6jNQz6J.png ---> no $offset is output here. That's why I was manually adding in the `, 0`. Alternatively, try `LIMIT $limit, $offset";` with no concatenation.

Comment: wrong link i guess. look at this http://i.imgur.com/NMDxYIz.png  this is the one with the $offset instead of a normal 0. btw I am discussing the same error in chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30755/discussion-between-sakibmoon-and-kees-sonnema

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->limit` only works with active records. Anyway, change your query to this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (`bedrijfcategorieen`) 
        JOIN `bedrijven` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven` = `bedrijven`.`idbedrijven` 
        JOIN `categorieen` ON `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idcategorieen` = `categorieen`.`idcategorieen` 
        WHERE (`Bedrijfsnaam` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Plaats` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Telefoonnummer` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Email` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Website` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Profiel` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Adres` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%' 
        OR `Categorie` LIKE '%".$this->input->post('search')."%') 
        AND (Postcode IN ($string))
        GROUP BY `Categorie`,  `bedrijfcategorieen`.`idbedrijven`
        LIMIT $offset,$limit";
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
```

One more thing, no need to use $this->db->limit